# Where to buy cheap mathematical ebooks, pdf books or research papers?

Tags: soft-question

> Where can I buy cheap a mathematical ebooks, pdf books or research papers?

Many thanks

Comment: I guess the cheapest way (outside US?) is to register to a university and use their library and internet access. Except that, it is probably a case per case problem depending on the book or the paper.

Comment: For awhile Springer was giving away free PDFs for math books more than ten years old, but it looks like that is no longer happening.  See this reddit discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3yib1k/so_it_looks_like_springer_is_offering_free_pdf/  and also this list with comment here: https://gist.github.com/bishboria/8326b17bbd652f34566a

Answer (score 2):

I always buy any PDF books, ebooks or research papers from here (only $5 for a book/paper):

https://www.fiverr.com/cheapebook/download-any-pdf-books-ebooks-or-papers-for-you?funnel=15b4bbdc-352c-43c8-825d-4690f9df2d55